# Empty string[] element in JSP

Tags: arrays, string, spring, jsp, jstl

I have a JSP that populates an int[] and string[] via Spring controller.  When a string value for an index is "", the JSP renders all of the values from the string[].

Controller populates string[] ids & values.
    `form.setIds(ids);`
    `form.setValues(values);`

The JSP loops through and populates a table.
    `<c:forEach items="${form.ids}" varStatus="status" var="id">`
    `<form:input path="values" value="${form.values[status.index]}" />`

When string[]:values contains: {"a","b","","d"}, elements 0,1,3 show as expected: 0="a", 1="b", 3="d".  Element 2 shows: "a,b,,d" for the output to the JSP for that line.

I've tried several ways to render, such as wrapping output in JSTL taglib, and changing to array lists instead of primitive string[].

I have a feeling I'm overlooking something :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your bug lies elsewhere. `${form.values[status.index]}` will indeed print nothing if the content of your array is really is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This one took a while.

The issue was that using path="values" on the form input, when we hit a empty element it would show all of "values" instead of the intended blank value.  The fix was to use path="values[${status.index}]" for the form input.

Also, in order to use an element, I had to switch my underlying form from using String[] objects to List objects.  This was due to the form not having an initialized String[] value upon loading, whereas I could init as ArrayList without having to specify a specific length to the string array.